# Reading multiple CSV files in Spark and make a DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using following code to read multiple csv files and and converting them to pandas df then concat it as a single pandas df. Finally converting again into spark DataFrame.  I want to skip conversion to pandas df part and simply want to have spark DataFrame.

**File Paths**

```
 abfss://xxxxxx/abc/year=2021/month=1/dayofmonth=1/hour=1/*.csv
 abfss://xxxxxx/abc/year=2021/month=1/dayofmonth=1/hour=2/*.csv
......
```

**Code**

```
list = []


for month in range(1,3,1):
  for day in range(1,31,1):
    for hour in range(0,24,1):
      file_location = "//xxxxxx/abc/year=2021/month="+str(month)+"/dayofmonth="+str(day)+"/hour="+str(hour)+"/*.csv"    
     
        try : 
          spark_df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(file_location)
          pandas_df = spark_df.toPandas()
          list.append(pandas_df)
    
    
        except AnalysisException as e:
          print(e)

final_pandas_df = pd.concat(list)
df = spark.createDataFrame(final_pandas_df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load all the files and apply a filter on the partitioning columns:

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("abfss://xxxxxx/abc/").filter(
    'year = 2021 and month between 1 and 2 and day between 1 and 30 and hour between 0 and 23'
)
```

Comment: The command just keep running , even I tried with `year = 2021 and month = 1 and day = 1 and hour between 0 and 10`

Comment: It might take some time if you have a lot of files or partitions. You could try adding `year=2021` to the loading path... it might help reduce the number of partitions that needs to be scanned.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo... you're right, it should be `dayofmonth`.

Comment: just a small query, if I want to fetch data from  Nov 2020  - Feb 2021 does `month between 11 and 2` will work ?

Comment: no, you need to specify two conditions for 11/2020-12/2020 and 1/2021-2/2021 separately

Comment: can we read it like we do with Dask? I tried but it takes a lot of time. `spark.read.csv(path+'*.csv')`. Can you help me what can be done here?